# Unexpected Undefined procedure

Tags: prolog

I want to assert some facts only once- if they haven't been asserted yet, so I make a check:

```
:- dynamic item/6.

init(Id, LastId, Depth) :-   
                        ruut(X,Y,Color),
                        (item(X,Y,Color,Depth,Id,LastId) -> true;       
                        assert(item(X,Y,Color,Depth,Id,LastId))),
                        fail.

init(_, _, _).
```

The point is to assert it only if it is not asserted yet. But I am getting an error:

```
ERROR: my_pgm:initsialiseeri_seisund/3: Undefined procedure: my_pgm:item/6
```

What I am doing wrong? Sorry for noob question, but I am really new to prolog!

Comment: what else compounds your code? do you initialize the values of `X` and `Y` in `ruut()`? you can do a `(\+ item(...) -> assert(...)), instead of going through the else statement.

Comment: Seems working... Are you aware you are asserting an item/6 for every ruut/3 ?

Comment: I wonder why init/3 get rewritten as initsialiseeri_seisund. Do you use some external tool?

Comment: Nope, I just changed function names to english to make it easier to understand for stackoverflow people :)

Comment: Please rewrite your question so that it uses only English and give it a meaningful title. If you are asking "how to implement assert that only asserts once", then title your post accordingly.

Comment: I don't think that you need such a complex variant. Its enough to use `ruut(X,Y,Color), \+(item(X,Y,Color,Depth,Id,LastId)), assert(item(X,Y,Color,Depth,Id,LastId)), fail; !, true.`. Btw it's always good to specify which prolog system you are using if you have some unexpected error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce this error in [online SWI-Prolog](http://ideone.com/MvpVb9) and it works as a charm.
Here is my sample of code:

```
:- dynamic foo/1.

lower(X,X).
lower(X,U):- X is U-1. % duplicate
lower(X,U):- U > 0, U1 is U-1, !, lower(X, U1).

init(U):-
  lower(X,U),
  \+(foo(X)), assert(foo(X)),
  fail; !, true.

show_all:-
  foo(X), print(X), nl, fail; !, true.

:- init(5), show_all.
```

Maybe you have some misusing of modules? I.e. you've defined `init/6` in one module and `assert/1` in another one and this cause some issues?